# Convert cURL request to Python-Requests request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, multipartform-data

I want to convert this cURL request to a Python-Requests request since I am working on a Python wrapper for a REST service

```
MS_WORD_DOCUMENT=...
CONTENT_TYPE="application/msword"

JSON_REQUEST="{\"documentType\" : \"$CONTENT_TYPE\"}"

curl -X POST -F "meta=$JSON_REQUEST;type=application/json" -F "data=@$MS_WORD_DOCUMENT" $SERVICE_ENDPOINT
```

How can I convert this to a Python3 Requests library request?

So far I've got to

```
data = {"metadata": {"documentType": "application/msword",
                     "Content-Type": "application/json"}}

req = requests.post(
    "https://text.s4.ontotext.com/v1/twitie",
    auth=("user", "pass"),
    headers={"Content-Type": "multipart/mixed"},
    data=data,
    files={"file": ("sample.docx", content,
                    "application/octet-stream")})
```

I don't know if that's the way to process multipart requests of the type with requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Curl command sends specific `multipart/form-data` field names; `meta` and `data`, and the [documentation for the API](http://docs.s4.ontotext.com/display/S4docs/Text+Analytics) specifies specific meta-types to be used.

Moreover, the metadata should be encoded to JSON.

The following should work:

```
import json
import requests

metadata = json.dumps({"documentType": "application/msword"})
files = {
    'meta': ('', metadata, 'application/json'),
    'data': ('sample.docx', content, 'application/octet-stream'),
}

req = requests.post(
    "https://text.s4.ontotext.com/v1/twitie",
    auth=("user", "pass"),
    files=files)
```

The `files` parameter is all that is needed here; each value is a tuple with a filename, the data to be sent, and the mimetype for that part.

Answer (score 1):

One good resource I've used for converting a cURL request to Python requests is [curlconverter](https://curl.trillworks.com/). You can enter your cURL request and it will format it for Python `requests`.

As a side note, it can also convert for PHP and Node.js.