# How to convert cURL in Python requests to change Jenkins config.xml file

Tags: python, curl, jenkins, python-requests

I have this cURL:

```
curl -X POST http://user:pass@blabla.com:8080/job/myproject/config.xml --data-binary "@new_config.xml"
```

I am basically trying to set a new config for a Jenkins installation by changing the pre-existing config.xml file.
I am trying to convert it to something like this in order to use it more flexibly in my code:

```
url     = "http://host:8080/job/myproject/config.xml"
auth    = ('user','pass')
payload = {"--data-binary": "@new_config.xml"}
headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/xml"}
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I know that I am using incorrectly the payload and the headers.How should I change them? 
I run it and I take a 500 responce code.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585800/convert-curl-request-to-python-requests-request) , but I am struggling to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--data-binary` switch means: post the command line argument *as the whole POST body*, without wrapping in `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-encoding` containers. `@` tells curl to load the data from a filename; `new_config.xml` in this case.

You'll need to open the file object to send the contents as the `data` argument:

```
url     = "http://host:8080/job/myproject/config.xml"
auth    = ('user','pass')
headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/xml"}
with open('new_config.xml', 'rb') as payload:
    r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Note that I pass the file object *directly* into `requests`; the data will then be read and pushed to the HTTP socket, streaming the data efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, it did a fine job! If I may ask you, could you please point me to some links to understand better cURL ? I inherited a lot of scripts that use it and I would most like to make the transition to something more elegant like requests.

Comment: I just use the `man curl` help page to understand what the command line does. There is a certain amount of basic HTTP knowledge required to understand both `curl` and `requests` here though.

Comment: I'll start from there then. My best!